# Get the href for an anchor tag (<a>) with hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, href

I have this link:

```
<a href="#main" /></a>
```

I want the href of the link. How can I get with jQuery the href of the link. When I try this:

```
var container = $(button).attr('href');
console.log(container);
```

I only get the # and not the main word. What i doing wrong?

Comment: What does _button_ store? `$('a').attr('href')`

Comment: You have invalid HTML syntax for `<a>` tag. It should not contain slash in the opening tag: `<a href="#main"></a>`.

Comment: @VisioN I ran it though w3's validator and it worked fine for me. The `href="#xyz"` attribute allows for jumping to named anchors

Comment: This SO link might be helpful. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3953299/get-hash-url-from-anchor-and-load-into-div

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('a').attr('href');
```

If you want to chose a more specific add a class to it like this `<a href="#main" class="main"/></a>`

and then to get then to get the href do this `$('a.main').attr('href');`

Answer (score 0):

Do This

```
var container = $('a').attr('href');
```

**or**

```
<a href="#main" id="button"> </a>
```

and

```
var container = $('a#button').attr('href');
```

This will solve your problem

Comment: Perhaps give your <a> an ID as well. i.e. `<a href="#main" id="button">` and use `var container = $('a#button').attr('href');`

Comment: No that wil not solve the problem. This is now my code:
var container = $("a").attr('href');
        console.log(container);
The results in console log #.

Comment: Check my answer again use `var container = $('a').attr('href');` @MikeVierwind

Comment: Adding tag type in selector will make it slower. When using specific Id, you dont have to refine selection.